# Webview is not showing bundle images on ios 5.1, works on other versions

Tags: iphone, ios, image, resources, webview

I'm developing application which shows page and images from app resources in webview. The page works fine, but the images aren't there when on iOS 5.1. When I'm testing it on iOS 4.3 or iOS 6.0 everything works like a charm; images are being shown properly. It seems like something's wrong with that exact system version. Here's the code I am using:

```
NSString *imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentImageName ofType:@"png"];
imgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"file://",imgPath];

content = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"{}" withString:imgPath];
myData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[webView loadData:myData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Content is the string with html. myData is NSData with html file. Image path is generated properly. As I mentioned before - everything works fine on iOS 4.3 and 6.0.

Here are the values of the data on iOS 5.1 emulator:

```
imgPath = file:///Users/deimos/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/98C3911D-46D6-49B6-BADC-6B463619EF5E/myApplication.app/pl.lproj/image01.png
```

content before replacing the image url:

```
<body>
<center><img src="{}" /></center>
</body>
```

content after replacing the image url:

```
<body>
<center><img src="file:///Users/deimos/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/98C3911D-46D6-49B6-BADC-6B463619EF5E/myApplication.app/pl.lproj/image01.png" /></center>
</body>
```

Comment: can you post the values of imgPath and content when the code runs in iOS 5?

Comment: I added the data you requested to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution to my problem. In the line:

```
[webView loadData:myData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

passing empty string to this method is wrong. It should be replaced by nil:

```
[webView loadData:myData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nil]];
```

With nil everything works fine on every system version.